# Arraylist of object overriding all indexes in AsyncTask callback

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Read couple of question here on stack overflow but couldn't find the working solution.

My scenario =>
In onActivityResult method, receiving a list which is send to Async Task for some background work. After performing some work, it sends back a list say **output**. After receiving **output** back in Async callback,  logged the**output** list and it works as expected.

Now from here, i want to put it in an Arraylist say **addProductModelListTemp**  so i can add further objects. But on adding other objects in background as illustrated in above scenario, **addProductModelListTemp** gets overridden all of its indexes with the last **output** list received in Async callback. Below is the code how i am updating **addProductModelListTemp**. **currentRowIdToInsertImages** is the index to insert object in **addProductModelListTemp** which is working fine(Not included here for simplicity)

```
new CompressFileAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse() {
                                @Override
                                public void processFinish(List<Uri> output) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
                                        Timber.e("Received from Async Class contains => " + output.get(i));
                                    }

                                    AddProductModel tempProductModel = new AddProductModel("", "", "", dummyList);// Dummy list is an empty list you can assume ... Tried setting it directly as well with the **output**
                                    addProductModelListTemp.add(tempProductModel);
                                    addProductModelListTemp.get(currentRowIdToInsertImages).setImagePathList(output);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < addProductModelListTemp.size(); i++) {
                                        Timber.e("addProductModelListTemp index " + i);
                                        for (int k = 0; k < addProductModelListTemp.get(i).getImagePathList().size(); k++) {
                                            Timber.e("addProductModelListTemp.get(i).getImagePathList() index " + k + " contains " + addProductModelListTemp.get(i).getImagePathList().get(k)); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).execute(imageURIList); // imageURIList is the list received in onActivityResult method
```

Below is the model class through which i am creating & updating objects.

```
   public AddProductModel(String size, String color, String quantity, List<Uri> imagePath) {

    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public void setImagePathList(List<Uri> imagePath) {
    if (this.imagePath.isEmpty()) {
        Timber.e("Image Path List not exists, adding");
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    } else {
        Timber.e("Image Path List exists, appending");
        this.imagePath.addAll(this.imagePath.size(), imagePath);
    }
} // Getter setter not attached for clarity}
```

The AsyncTask class is

```
class CompressFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Uri>, Void, List<Uri>> {
    public AsyncResponse asyncResponse = null;

    public CompressFileAsyncTask(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Uri> doInBackground(List<Uri>... imageUriList) {
        List<Uri> fileList = imageUriList[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            filesAdded.add(Uri.parse(compressImage(String.valueOf(fileList.get(i)))));
        }
        return filesAdded;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Uri> uriArrayList) {
        asyncResponse.processFinish(uriArrayList);
    }
}
```

And the interface itself

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
public void processFinish(List<Uri> output);
```

}

Comment: Can you please share your expected input and output to the async task. And clarify what you mean by "addProductModelListTemp gets overridden all of its indexes"

Comment: "addProductModelListTemp" is the arraylist of AddProductModel.


"imageUriList" is the intentData i am receiving in onActivityResult method.


"output" is the list i am receiving after AsyncTask finishes and trigger the callback

This is the ImageURIList i am receiving in onActivityResult method when i selected three images

ImageURIList index 0 content://media/external/images/media/140871
ImageURIList index 1 content://media/external/images/media/139181
ImageURIList index 2 content://media/external/images/media/139180

Comment: I just send them in Async & get three compressed images back.
I created an object of AddProductModel & saved these images in "imagePath" list & then i saved this object in  "addProductModelListTemp" list so i can use it later.

Now i have three images on index 0 of "addProductModelListTemp". Right ?

Now i called the gallery again & picked 5 images which i tried to saved on second index of "addProductModelListTemp" by same method used above. Now if i log my "addProductModelListTemp" array, it contains two indexes but on both index, the "imagePath" list contains 5 same images

Comment: I am expecting that i would retreive two objects from "addProductModelListTemp" now. And in first object, "imagePath" list will contain three indexes & for second object, the "imagePath" will be of 5 indexes.

Comment: Can you please share the processFinish() method call. I have a feeling that you are updating the same image list in the AsyncTask over and over.

Comment: @RishabhJain , please check the edit. Updated AsyncTask class & interface.

Comment: @Umair where is the field filesAdded initialised. Do you clear the list before each AsyncTask execution?

Comment: Yes, i am clearing it as soon as onActivityResult get called. filesAdded is also a list added in global scope.

Comment: Timber.e("Received from Async Class contains => " + output.get(i));

This gets printed as expected upon adding newer items .... Just adding it to the "addProductModelListTemp" makes things go wrong. Not getting an idea why it is behaving like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are modifying the same list object and storing it in each index of `addProductModelListTemp`. You need to make `filesAdded` a local variable.

```
@Override
    protected List<Uri> doInBackground(List<Uri>... imageUriList) {
        List<Uri> fileList = imageUriList[0];
        List<Uri> filesAdded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            filesAdded.add(Uri.parse(compressImage(String.valueOf(fileList.get(i)))));
        }
        return filesAdded;
    }
```

Comment: Well, you are right. Declaring it as local works. Still thinking why filesAdded.clear() doesn't work here.

Comment: When you clear the list, you remove all the items from that list object. All the indexes of addProductModelListTemp store the reference to the same filesAdded object. So when you make any changes to filesAdded, that is reflected all over.